# Getting PowerShell Script Location at Run Time in PowerShell Command line

Tags: powershell, windows-scripting

I am running a PowerShell script and calling `$MyInvocation.PSCommandPath` within the script and it returns null.

The script is meant to be run within a PowerShell Console because it has command line parameters as such:

`.\Users\MyScripts\myscript.ps1 -file1 .\file1.exe -file2 .\file2.exe`

Inside my script is the following lines:

```
$mypath = $MyInvocation.PSCommandPath
echo $mypath
```

This echo returns nothing is there a way to get the path of myscript.ps1?

I am expecting the script to run and remember path of the script to execute again after a reboot. I was wondering if this was possible using this automatic variable.

Comment: why don't you try something like `$myInvocation.myCommand.path`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the dedicated `$PSCommandPath` automatic variable instead:

```
echo $PSCommandPath
```

The `$PSCommandPath` and `$PSScriptRoot` auto variables were introduced in Windows PowerShell 3.0, if you need compatibility with PowerShell 2.0, do:

```
if ($PSVersionTable['PSVersion'].Major -lt 3){
  $scriptPath = $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
}
else {
  $scriptPath = $PSCommandPath
}
```

Comment: Thank you it worked. Why did the other one not work?

Comment: @Wandering I can't remember when the behavior of `$MyInvocation` changed, but `$PSCommandPath` and `$PSScriptRoot` auto variables were introduced in PowerShell 3.0 - so if that's the oldest version you need to support => always use `$PSCommandPath`/`$PSScriptRoot`